# How can I "join" two tables and know when to trigger setState?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have two tables, this is the JSON structure:

```
"business" : {
  "-KTzPzkWpUJCIQQT_b6v" : {
    "name" : "Superstore",
    "products": {
      "-KU8qg0-5R7H6F6NCc-y": true,
      "-KU8qg04fI_CoXVWM_dx": true,
      "-KU8qg05NLtPNzVF_n70": true
    }
  }
},
"product" : {
  "-KU8qg0-5R7H6F6NCc-y" : {
    "name" : "Milk"
  },
  "-KU8qg03Jassok7BWFxz" : {
    "name" : "Nails"
  },
  "-KU8qg04fI_CoXVWM_dw" : {
    "name" : "Screws"
  },
  "-KU8qg04fI_CoXVWM_dx" : {
    "name" : "Tent"
  },
  "-KU8qg04fI_CoXVWM_dy" : {
    "name" : "Paint"
  },
  "-KU8qg05NLtPNzVF_n70" : {
    "name" : "Candy"
  },
  "-KU8qg05NLtPNzVF_n71" : {
    "name" : "Mittens"
  },
  "-KU8qg05NLtPNzVF_n72" : {
    "name" : "Bread"
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is select the store using the key and then, in one go, also find the product names for the products that the store is carrying.

I have the code for selecting the details of the store:

```
var currentBusinessData
var currentBusiness = firebase.database().ref("business/" + businessKey)
  currentBusiness.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    currentBusinessData = snapshot.val()        
    this.setState({isLoading: false})
  });
```

I could then add a map that goes through all the products and selects the name, but since this is asynchronous I don't know how to ensure that I have the details for all products before changing state (at least not without doing some painful counter thing) + I would have to create a local array to store the product details, which also seems a bit unoptimal.

Any suggestions on how to best solve this?

Comment: The counter is one of the simplest ways I know to do this. Alternatively you could call setState after each joined item is loaded and simply let React sort out what part of the UI to update. It's quite efficient at that.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I was just hoping for a more convinient solution than managing both a local counter and local array, but maybe I will wrap in some kind og convinience class. Triggering setState everytime is not a solution in this case.

Comment: Don't underestimate React's ability to optimize repaints (as long as you map the child nodes' key to each React item).

Comment: Its more a matter of this particular view being pretty simple and that it would appear almost empty if it tenderer before these items are ready to display.

Comment: Alternatives are to simply store the pertinent product information under each store too. Data duplication to simplify code is quite common in NoSQL databases. Oh, and `once()` returns a promise, so you could probably put all of them in a `Promise.all()`.